# Calculating percentages of "1s" in one column based on two other columns in R

Tags: r

I am a R Newbie. Sorry for asking basic question. 
I have "data" that consists of three columns (as an example) named data$engine, data$unit, and data$AvailableLeft. data$AvailableLeft is dummy (0 or 1). And for each unique value of data$engine, there can be several values of data$unit. I would like to calculate percent of "1s" in data$AvailableLeft for each value of data$engine and data$unit respectively. I have hundred thousands of rows but pasted the first 13 rows only.

```
 data$engine  data$unit     data$AvailableLeft
    10158       207                1
    10158       207                0
    10158       207                1
    10158       207                0
    10147       142                1
    10147       142                1
    10147       142                1
    10147       142                0
    10147       142                1
    10147       142                0
    10147       142                1
    10161       244                0
    10161       244                0
```

I would like to have my output in this format:

```
    data$engine  data$unit            Percentage
     10158          207                  20%
     10147          142                  10%
     10161          244                  3%
       .             .                    .
       .             .                    .
       .             .                    .
```

I tried these codes but was not successful:

```
 ##calculate the percentage of "1s" for whole data and not for each data$engine and data$unit
sum(data$AvailableLeft==1)/length(data$AvailableLeft) 

# tried to do it in parts but was not able to divide the two columns at last...
df11 <- data.frame(data$engine, data$unit, data$AvailbleLeft)
leftwarn1=aggregate(data$AvailableLeft ~ data$engine + data$unit, data =    df11, sum) #Counting number of "1s" per unit per engine
leftwarn10 = count(data$AvailableLeft == 0, c("data$engine","data$unit")) #counting number of "1 and 0" per unit per engine
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dta <- read.table(text = "
           data$engine  data$unit     data$AvailableLeft
              10158       207                1
              10158       207                0
              10158       207                1
              10158       207                0
              10147       142                1
              10147       142                1
              10147       142                1
              10147       142                0
              10147       142                1
              10147       142                0
              10147       142                1
              10161       244                0
              10161       244                0", 
                  header = TRUE)

# dta[, 3] for example, returns the third column.
# aggregate as its helpfile (?aggregate) says allows you to compute summary statistics of data subsets

aggregate(dta[, 3], by = list(dta[, 1], dta[, 2]), mean)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am receiving this error: Error in aggregate(dta[, DASlane$AvailableLeft], by = list(dta[, DASlane$Device],  : 
  object 'dta' not found...

Comment: Your data.frame is called data not dta and you are not sub-setting correctly

Comment: Sorry i am pretty new to R. I tried with "data" instead of "dta"... can you please guide me on this? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The solution I though is pretty long, but it worked fine for me:

```
data<-read.table(paste0(file.path(Sys.getenv("USERPROFILE"),"Desktop"),
"/dta.txt"), header = TRUE) # I transcribed your examble above to notepad and
# saved it as dta.txt, so I could read the table in R 

enginevalues<-unique(data$engine) # Unique values of "engine" column
unitvalues<-unique(data$unit) # Unique values of "unit" column
output<-matrix(ncol=3) # Matrix where I stored the outputs
digitsafterdot<-2 # Number of digits after dot (or comma, whathever)

# After, I did two for loops: one for "engine" and other for "unit" values
# You can understand it as a combinatorial analysis
for(eng in enginevalues){
  dteng<-data[data[,"engine"]==eng,]
  for(un in unitvalues){
    dtunit<-dteng[dteng[,"unit"]==un,]
# Percentage: Number of 1's x 100 divided by the total number of AvailableLeft values
    percentage<-round(sum(dtunit[,"AvailableLeft"] == 1)*100/nrow(dtunit),
                                                    digits=digitsafterdot)
    # Division by zero is not allowed!
    if(nrow(dtunit) == 0) percentage<-0
    output<-rbind(output,c(eng,un,percentage))

  }
}
output<-output[-1,] # Just removing the initial NA values
colnames(output)<-c("engine","unit","percentage") # Renaming the output

output
#      engine  unit   percentage
# [1,]  10158  207      50.00
# [2,]  10158  142       0.00
# [3,]  10158  244       0.00
# [4,]  10147  207       0.00
# [5,]  10147  142      71.43
# [6,]  10147  244       0.00
# [7,]  10161  207       0.00
# [8,]  10161  142       0.00
# [9,]  10161  244       0.00

# Output without zero values
outputnozeros<-output[output[,"percentage"]!=0.00,]

outputnozeros
#      engine  unit   percentage
# [1,]  10158  207      50.00
# [2,]  10147  142      71.43
```

The solution by @NBATrends also works fine and is compact, but the one presented here gives you some additional control over the loop. I suppose that both solutions work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing suggestions from you all, i scripted it this way and it seemingly works (not sure):

```
df11 <- data.frame(data$engine, data$unit, data$AvailableLeft) 
warn = aggregate(data$AvailableLeft ~ data$engine + data$unit, data = df11, mean)
```

Any comments please?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large data frame try using data.table library .used the data created by NBATrends

```
library(data.table)
dta <- read.table(text = "
           data$engine  data$unit     data$AvailableLeft
                  10158       207                1
                  10158       207                0
                  10158       207                1
                  10158       207                0
                  10147       142                1
                  10147       142                1
                  10147       142                1
                  10147       142                0
                  10147       142                1
                  10147       142                0
                  10147       142                1
                  10161       244                0
                  10161       244                0", 
                  header = TRUE)
dt  <- as.data.table(dta)
dt[,sum(data.AvailableLeft)*100/.N,.(data.engine,data.unit)]

 data.engine    data.unit       V1
1:       10158       207  50.00000
2:       10147       142  71.42857
3:       10161       244  0.00000
```

For exactly your requirement this should be more appropriate

```
dt[,paste(as.character(round(sum(data.AvailableLeft)*100/.N,2)),"%"),.(data.engine,data.unit)]
```

which gives

```
  data.engine   data.unit      V1
1:       10158       207     50 %
2:       10147       142  71.43 %
3:       10161       244      0 %
```

To figure out how to get the percentage of `0` in `data$AvailableLeft` should be trivial from here and I would leave that for the user

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
subset(as.data.frame(with(df, prop.table(table(engine, unit, AvailableLeft))*100)), AvailableLeft==1, select=-AvailableLeft)
```

---

With regards to your comment:

```
df <- read.table(col.names=c("engine", "unit", "left"), text="
    10158       207                1
    10158       207                0
    10158       207                1
    10158       207                0
    10147       142                1
    10147       142                1
    10147       142                1
    10147       142                0
    10147       142                1
    10147       142                0
    10147       142                1
    10161       244                0
    10161       244                0")
subset(as.data.frame(with(df, prop.table(table(engine, unit, left))*100)), left==1, select=-left)
#   engine unit     Freq
# 10  10147  142 38.46154
# 11  10158  142  0.00000
# 12  10161  142  0.00000
# 13  10147  207  0.00000
# 14  10158  207 15.38462
# 15  10161  207  0.00000
# 16  10147  244  0.00000
# 17  10158  244  0.00000
# 18  10161  244  0.00000
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried, R returns with all fields filled with <NA> values, and prompts [reached getOption('max.print") -- omitted 255502 rows ]

Comment: Please review the edit - seems to works with the example data (?). It's maybe because I forgot to substitute `left` by `AvailableLeft`...

Comment: I am editing your script accordingly, but still error. Thanks for your time.

df11 <- data.frame(DASlane$Device, DASlane$Trip, DASlane$AvailableLeft)
subset(as.data.frame(with(df11, prop.table(table(DASlane$Device, DASlane$Trip, DASlane$AvailableLeft))*100)), DASlane$AvailableLeft==1, select=-DASlane$AvailableLeft)

Comment: Remove `DASlane$` and substitute `df11` by `DASlane` in the (probably) 2nd statement?